# angular cli showing error "Property 'open' does not exist on type 'NgbModule'" while using NgbModule

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-bootstrap

i am trying to open a modal from a component and pass a component into modal using ".open" method as per documentation of @ng-bootstrap but i am getting the error in angular cli that .open is not a method

i have also added "NgbModule.forRoot()" in imports in NgbModule and followed all the steps as per documentation but still getting the error.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Angular2SocialLoginModule } from "angular2-social-login";
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { LoginModule } from "./login/login.module";
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { ConfigService } from "./config-service";
import { ErrorMessageService } from "./share/error-messages.service"
import { MdTooltipModule } from '@angular/material';

import { CustomProfileComponent } from './custom-profile/custom-profile.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { HttpModule, JsonpModule }    from '@angular/http';
import { S3UploadService } from "./custom-profile/fileupload.component.service";
import {HomeModule } from "./Home/home-component-module";
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';

import {ConfirmPopupService} from "./confirm-popup.service";


import 'hammerjs';

import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';    

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CustomProfileComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule,
    FormsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    LoginModule,
    MdTooltipModule,
    Angular2SocialLoginModule,
    HomeModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()

  ],
  providers: [ConfigService, ErrorMessageService,S3UploadService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
Angular2SocialLoginModule.loadProvidersScripts(providers);
```

here is my modal component which i want to passto the "open" method

**confirmation.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { Observable, Subject, ReplaySubject } from "rxjs";


@Component({
    selector: 'ngbd-modal-confirm',
    template: `
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm {{name}}</h4>

            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')" style="float:right">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Are you sure you want to confirm this {{name}}!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="yesClick()">YES</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="noClick()">NO</button>
        </div>
    `
})
export class NgbdModalConfirmationComponent {
    @Input() name;
    @Input() isConfirmed = new Subject();
    constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }

    yesClick() {
        this.isConfirmed.next(true);
        console.log(this.isConfirmed);
        this.activeModal.close('Close click');
    }

    noClick() {
        this.isConfirmed.next(false);
        console.log(this.isConfirmed);
        this.activeModal.close('Close click');
    }
}
```

And the component in which i want to use it..

**profile.component.ts**

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from "@angular/router"
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
// import { ErrorMessageService } from "../share/error-messages.service";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
import{ProfileService} from './profile-component.service';
import {ConfirmPopupService} from "../confirm-popup.service";
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {NgbdModalConfirmationComponent} from '../confirmation.component';
@Component({
  //selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css'],
  providers: [ProfileService,ConfirmPopupService]
})

export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private profileService: ProfileService,private _fb: FormBuilder,private modalService:NgbModule) {
  }


deleteEdu(obj){

    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalConfirmationComponent);

    modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'KYC';

       modalRef.componentInstance.isConfirmed.subscribe(value => {
            console.log(value);
            if(value)
              {
                //perform delete operation
              }
            else{
               //dont perform delete operation
                }
         });
}
```

i havent posted the whole code of profile.component.ts as it is very long only the part where i want to use Ngbmodule have posted.

so basically what i wanted to do is when user click delete then confirmation modal will appear if user click "yes" then delete operations will get executed else nothing will happen.

sorry for not posting the whole code earlier. thank you.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any one having an issue it would be better

Comment: Same issue, any Luck?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In your `profile.component.ts` you are importing `NgbModule`. Try changing it to `NgbModal` and see if that fixes the error.

You have:

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

Change to

```
import {NgbModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

Then change the constructor. Maybe that will help.